# React: How to set state to possibly increasing list<li> of items?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

A page I am working on has a list of `Categories`. Within the `Categories`, there is a list of items. Each item has a `name`. At the bottom of the list of items, there is a "Create new item" button.

The issue I am having is I do not know how to attach the newly created `Item` as part of my items state.

How do I have the app `setState({})` to the newly created Item?

```
class ActiveCategory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      updatedItemName: "",
      updatedItemCost: "",
      updatingId: "",
      activeCategory: {
        name: "",
        items: []
      }
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e, inputType, id) {
    if (inputType === "name") this.setState({ updatedItemName: e });
    else if (inputType === "cost") this.setState({ updatedItemCost: e });

    this.setState({ updatingId: id });
  }

  onClick() {
    this.props.updateItem(
      this.state.updatedItemName,
      this.state.updatedItemCost,
      this.state.updatingId
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ activeCategory: this.props.activeCategory });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.setState({ activeCategory: this.props.activeCategory });
  }

  render() {
    let items = [];

    if (this.props.activeCategory !== undefined) {
      items = this.props.activeCategory.items.map(item => (
        <li key={item[2]}>
          <input
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e.target.value, "name", item[2])}
            defaultValue={item[0]}
          />
          <input
            type="number"
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e.target.value, "cost", item[2])}
            defaultValue={item[1]}
          />
        </li>
      ));
    }

    return (
      <div className="card col-md-9">
        <h2 className="text-center">{this.props.activeCategory.name}</h2>
        {items}
        <button onClick={() => this.onClick} className="btn btn-success">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have the defaultValue={item[0]} property instead of a value={item[0]} because then I could not change the value.

Comment: `setState(prevState => ({ items: [...prevState.items, NEW_ITEM_HERE] }))`

Comment: Could you include the code you have written so far?

Comment: Might be a little messy, I am all over the place with this one :S

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I see no code trying to add a new item to the array. Is that present in the parent component?

Comment: No you are correct, I meant to add the button afterwards but got side tracked with just being able to update the items that appear now. My current problem is I don't know how to 'map' the state to each item, as well as newly created items.